# Upgrading an Intel Core 2 Duo T5750 to T9500

Tags: laptop, cpu, motherboard, upgrade, intel-core2

I have an old laptop ([Acer Aspire 8920](https://www.cnet.com/products/acer-aspire-8920/specs/)), which I love very much, but I'd love to upgrade the processor. The current processor is an Intel Core 2 Duo T5750. What is the best processor I can upgrade to?  I am getting conflicting messages.

According to [CPU-Upgrade](http://www.cpu-upgrade.com/CPUs/Intel/Core_2_Duo_Mobile/T5750.html), the best processor that's compatible with the old one is T7800 (still at 35W).

According to the [Service Manual](http://www.s-manuals.com/pdf/notebook/acer/acer_aspire_8920_series_service_guide.pdf) (page 116), this model of laptop has the option to ship with a T9500! (which I assume means it would come on the same motherboard, as the service manual lists only one model of motherboard).

Which one is right? Which is the best processor I can put in the laptop?

Comment: I would trust the acer pdf, the T9500 can be used in that laptop and is the most powerful of all the choices.

Comment: But is it worth the trouble? http://cpuboss.com/cpus/Intel-Core2-Duo-T9500-vs-Intel-Core2-Duo-T5750 In a nutshell, you'd be replacing a XIX horse carriage with a slightly newer model. Perhaps better to think about (and save to) a modern car.

Comment: @MichaelBay - That's what I would do, but I'm struggling to find an 18.4" laptop that's a nice to use as the Acer. (especially the keyboard and trackpad, which are pretty much the best I have used on a laptop).  18.4" laptops are few and far between. I could go for one of the Alienware 18s, but they're much heavier, and I'd want to try out the mechanics before I bought one.  Also, there's just no need. The Acer is almost perfect, except for the fact that it occasionally struggles with a fullscreen YouTube video (Although strangely it handles Netflix fine).

Comment: The T9500 won't make any noticeable difference.

Comment: @MichaelBay - That's hard to believe, looking at the benchmarks half way down the page. The improvements are about 30% - 50%.

Comment: *The T9500 won't make any noticeable difference* **in real life**. And graphics performance, including that for html5, has little to do with the CPU. The old "GeForce 9650M GS - 512 MB" is way more a limiting factor than the CPU itself. But it's your money, you do what you want at the end of the day and the above is just my opinion.

Comment: @MichaelBay - It worked, and video playback is noticeably improved.

Answer (score 0):

The results are in.  You certainly can simply replace a T5750 with a T9500, and the speed improvement is instantly noticeable. Even videos play better.

There's just one extra step in Windows. Uninstall the original processor's drivers from Device Manager. Then reboot, to see the new processor's drivers automatically installed. This should then enable the higher clock speed of the new processor.